# How to calulate how long it takes to download a file

Tags: php

I have written scripts to download XML data via HTTP. I would like to record (in a database) how long it takes to download the XML file. Does PHP have a built in function for timing the length of a download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has built in functions to record time. Many people use [microtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to profile their functions.

Here's an example from the manual:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(1);

// PUT YOUR DOWNLOAD FUNCTION HERE - GWB

$time_end = microtime(1);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Downloaded in ".round($time,5)." seconds\n";
?>
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** As [@toon81](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946475/toon81) mentioned in a comment on the other post, you have to watch out for time changes on the server. As mentioned in the [comments section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php#104053) of the [microtime manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

*"However it is true that result depends of gettimeofday() call. [...] If system time change, result of this function can be unpredictable (much greater or less than zero)."*

Comment: well, the previous comment has been deleted. Two cents on this answer: depending on the function you use to download, the PHP-Script may continue to run (asynchronous download) - so if your times are too low, check the download-function you use.

Comment: This is giving me some metrics. It's different each time. Is this not accurate?

Comment: my bad. It was me who actually misread the question. I confused upload and download. I apologize for that.

Comment: @RPM The download times *will* be different each time. That's just how the Internet works. To get an average download time, you need to record it many times, and average the results.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel even with uploading data, your comment would still have been incorrect - anyways, as long as PHP is involved in either down- or upload (and even if just to pipe the file through), you may check the times.

Comment: @Lars no, with upload you can't measure anything.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel yes, you can. In the above function, simply insert an `ftp_put()`. As long as the function to down/upload is synchronous and blocking the script during excecution (which is e.g. not the case for certain `cURL()` functions), the timing works fine.

Comment: @Lars an ftp what? I am talking of regular HTTP upload.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Why should an `HTTP PUT` via socket, a jabber-file-transfer or a self-written-protocol be any different? Anyway, let's kill this discussion here - I think we may be talking past one another. ;)

Comment: @Lars PHP is able not only send files but also receive them, using HTTP POST, which is called HTTP upload.

Comment: Oy. You guys are polluting my answer with a discussion in the comments. Zap your comments, and have at it here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181291/can-i-measure-the-time-it-takes-a-file-to-upload-to-a-php-script

Answer (score 1):

Make an UNIX timestamp right before and after the download and calculate the difference.

```
$start = time();
//Download
$end = time();
$time = $end - $start;
//Send to db
```

Comment: Not sure why your answer got downvoted so much, bro. Seems a perfectly legitimate answer to me.

Comment: It's not. First of all, the `time` function is in seconds and therefore not suitable for profiling functions. Second of all, timing stuff just isn't that simple. Check out the comments here: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php