# How can I measure the time it takes a file to upload to a PHP script?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect how long it takes for a file to upload (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931959/detect-how-long-it-takes-for-a-file-to-upload-php)

I am trying to measure the time a script takes to upload a file to a PHP script, inside the receiving script. Here's a short example:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Upload:
    <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<?php

$upload_time = time() - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
echo $upload_time . " seconds.";
```

I've submitted 4MB, 25MB, 100MB and 1.4GB files. They took anything from a fraction of a second, to almost a minute, yet the script above always yielded 0 seconds.

**NOTE:** *I know that this is a duplicate question*, but the accepted answer on the other question did not work for me (at least, initially):
[Detect how long it takes for a file to upload (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931959/detect-how-long-it-takes-for-a-file-to-upload-php)

I've tried it using PHP 5.3.3 with Apache 2.2.16 on Ubuntu 10.4.

**UPDATE:**

I've discovered that both the Apache header and Ajax solutions work. In fact, the solution on the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931959/detect-how-long-it-takes-for-a-file-to-upload-php) **also** works.

The critical element to making these solutions work is to ensure that the following values in the php.ini are sufficiently high:

```
memory_limit = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
post_max_size = 1000M
```

I am accepting the Apache header solution, since it only uses PHP.